# Grails initialization of classes

Tags: class, grails, groovy, initialization

I have a question about initialization wiith groovy/grails.  When I have the following class, sInstance doesn't get passed into the SService initialization.

```
class A {

    String sInstance
    String app
    String dbInstance

    SService s = new SService(sInstance:sInstance, app:app)
}
```

SService class:

```
class SService {

    String sInstance
    String app

public getSInstance{
    return sInstance
    }
}
```

This returns null, where

```
class A {

    String sInstance
    String app
    String dbInstance

public initializeSService{
    SService s = new SService(sInstance:sInstance, app:app)
    }
}
```

returns the sInstance variable from the SService class.

Why is that and how can I have SService object initialized with the class A constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do something like this:

```
class A {

    String sInstance
    String app
    String dbInstance

    SService s = new SService(sInstance:sInstance, app:app)
}
```

The problem with that is when you are creating an instance of SService, sInstance has not been initialized yet.  If you want to pass sInstance to a constructor of some other class from within the A class, you are going to have to do it after sInstance has been assigned a value, like a method that is called after A is fully constructed.

EDIT:

Trying to clarify something from the comments below:

```
class A {
    String sInstance
    String app
    String dbInstance

    void anyMethod() {
        // this will work as long as you have initialized sInstance
        SService s = new SService(sInstance:sInstance, app:app)
    }
}
```

Depending on what you are really trying to do, maybe something in this direction:

```
class A {
    String sInstance
    String app
    String dbInstance
    SService s

    void initializeS() {
        if(s == null) {
            // this will work as long as you have initialized sInstance
            s = new SService(sInstance:sInstance, app:app)
        }
    }
}
```

Or:

```
class A {
    String sInstance
    String app
    String dbInstance
    SService theService

    SService getTheService() {
        if(theService == null) {
            // this will work as long as you have initialized sInstance
            theService = new SService(sInstance:sInstance, app:app)
        }
        theService
    }

    def someMethodWhichUsesTheService() {
        getTheService().doSomethingToIt()
    }
}
```

Comment: If i use another method (after A is fully constructed) then I do not have access to it as a class variable.  How can I construct it as a class variable?

Comment: Why wouldn't you have access to it inside of a method?  Any method defined inside of `A` has access to all of the fields and properties defined in `A`.

Comment: If I do "def startService()" and put the initialize call for SService in there, then in another method I do not have access to the service I created (s).  I get the following error message No such property: s

Comment: You do if you declare the SService as a field in the class.  See my example above that includes a field called `theService`.

Comment: See `someMethodWhichUsesTheService`.

Comment: The way I was looking for was the way right under "Depending on what you are really trying to do, maybe something in this direction:" and not the or.  Thanks